# How to remove survey variables at the end of answering?

Tags: php, html

I have following code:

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting",0);
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
if (isset($_GET['pollid']))
    $_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
else
    $_SESSION['pollid'] = 0;
    echo 'kysitlus l6ppenud';
$questions = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
        }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['answering']['count']=count($questions);
}

    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $x = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
    $result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $type = mysql_result($result3, 0);
    if ($type=='3'){
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/valikvastustega_kysimusele_vastamine.php'>";
        }

    if ($type=='1'){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
    $answer=$_POST['option'];
    }
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
    $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
}
$_SESSION['answering']['index']++;

?>
```

It is code which prints out answers from database where `kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid']`.(It is not the full code, there are two seperate files more for echoing and answering questions).

My question is, what and where should I write into my code, so the $_SESSION['answering'] variables will be deleted at the end of answering, so I could answer again to other surveys during same session without closing and reopening the browser.

EDIT:

I changed my code, and now I can answer to survey many times, but it will always be first survey I answered, it doesn't matter which pollid I insert from url, my code looks now like that:

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting",0);
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
if (isset($_GET['pollid']))
    $_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
else
    $_SESSION['pollid'] = 0;
    //echo 'kysitlus l6ppenud';
$questions = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
        }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['answering']['count']=count($questions);
}

if ($_SESSION['answering']['index']==$_SESSION['answering']['count']){
if(isset($_SESSION['answering'])){
  unset($_SESSION['answering']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['questions']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['index']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['count']);
  exit("kysitlus l6ppenud");
  }
}

    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $x = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
    $result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $type = mysql_result($result3, 0);
    if ($type=='3'){
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/valikvastustega_kysimusele_vastamine.php'>";
        }

    if ($type=='1'){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
    $answer=$_POST['option'];
    }
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
    $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
}
$_SESSION['answering']['index']++;


?>
```

Then I changed the line if `($_SESSION['answering']['index']==$_SESSION['answering']['count'])` to if `($_SESSION['answering']['index']==$_SESSION['answering']['count']+1)` and now I can answer to any survey but new problem appears. When survey is over the message 'kysitlus l6ppenud' doesn't appear right away. I have to reload the page, and message appears then. I am sure the problem has simple solution, but I cant figure it out know, I should change order of some code or something. Could anyone point me the right direction?

Comment: First you should fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities before attempting to fix something else.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem this way:

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting",0);
include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';
if (isset($_GET['pollid']))
    $_SESSION['pollid']=(int) $_GET['pollid'];
else
    $_SESSION['pollid'] = 0;
$questions = array();
if (!isset($_SESSION['answering'])) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from katse_kysimused where kysimustik_id="' . $_SESSION['pollid'] . '"');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $questions[] = $row['kysimus'];
        }
    $_SESSION['answering']['questions'] = $questions;
    $_SESSION['answering']['index'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['answering']['count']=count($questions);
}


    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $x = $_SESSION['answering']['index'];
    $result3 = mysql_query('SELECT tyyp_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x] . '"');
    $type = mysql_result($result3, 0);
    if ($type=='3'){
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/valikvastustega_kysimusele_vastamine.php'>";
        }

    if ($type=='1'){
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/tekstkysimusele_vastamine2.php'>";
        }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['option'])){
    $answer=$_POST['option'];
    }
    $result2 = mysql_query('SELECT kysimus_id FROM katse_kysimused where kysimus= "' . $_SESSION['answering']['questions'][$x -1] . '"');
    $q_id = mysql_result($result2, 0);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO katse_vastused2 (id, vastus,kysimus_id, vastustik_id) VALUES (NULL,"' . $answer . '","' . $q_id . '","1")');
    if ($_SESSION['answering']['index']==$_SESSION['answering']['count']){
if(isset($_SESSION['answering'])){
  unset($_SESSION['answering']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['questions']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['index']);
  unset ($_SESSION['answering']['count']);
  exit("kysitlus l6ppenud");
  }
}
}
$_SESSION['answering']['index']++;


?>
```